# flash/flex 4 application - why/when it works differently in different environemnts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Since a week I am seeing my flex 4 application is working differently in my local environment and the remotely deployed environment.

I copied entire bin-debug folder into the remote and I have no clue why this happens? its the same swf copied into the remote and its the same browser I am using to run the app but it just behaves differently.

Well, I read some of the posts who has issues with layouts appear differently in the local and remote but let me clarify you that in my case I have not see layout issues but its the code seems working differently. **Like, I have implemented dynamic masking, collusion detection, depth sorting algorithms in my code which works perfect in local environment and wont in remote environment.**

If you think it could be cache problem, then let me tell you. I have cleared cache of my browser (in fact I do it almost ever time before I run the app). Also, I have completely deleted files in the remote and copied all the files again. I have also tried by deploying the "release" build also but the same thing. I have did each of the above steps multiple times in different combinations to see the fix but no luck yet.

I am sure this should't matter

I am using WAMP in local environment and LAMP in remote

To make sure I am seeing the latest version, I have added a version number and displayed in debug window. both environments shows the same number so this tells both are same versions.

These are all the files I have copied along with my main swf

```
framework_4.0.0.14159.swf
main.swf
osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swf
rpc_4.0.0.14159.swf
spark_4.0.0.14159.swf
sparkskins_4.0.0.14159.swf
test.swf
textLayout_1.0.0.595.swf
```

I dont know how to resolve this. please help

Comment: To be 100% certain you are seeing the latest version, make it display a version number or something unique.

Comment: well, i dont know why I thought of doing it 4-5 times and each time i stopped to search how to get version number and quicly skipped it as I thought its not so imortant. i did even before posting this question too :P i will update what i find

Comment: how do i tell the difference? I highlighted the issues in OP that I am seeing right now.

Comment: My current suggestion would be to use a proxy (charles is my favorite, there's others though like wireshark or even firefox plugins like firebug that'll do it for ya).  Double check what's going on with the communication between the client and the server be sure it's not having any issues getting any of the files.  Make sure you're using the debug version of flash player http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html report on any errors you see with any of these.  If none of this works put traces in your methods running the algorithms and use the FlashLog.txt/Vizzy

Comment: @shaunhusain thanks for reply. have you ever seen or heard of this situation?

Comment: Not without it being some sort of an error that just wasn't being seen.  Sometimes when things are deployed to a server you end up with security errors that you don't see when testing locally, aside from that if it's the same flash player and same environment generally you don't have any difference in errors (even different environments rarely matter, only different flash player versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks shaunhusain thanks a lot. I used the trace using the snipping tools and found the bug.

Its all in the **host name**. I was finding the **asset type** based on the **extension** found in the **url**. I remove transparent pixels if the asset type is an "image" and ignore if its not an image (xml,swf etc.,)

and this is the code which determines the asset type (note the default value is 'unknown')

```
    private function getAssetType(url:String):String{

        var type:String = "unknown";

        var ext:String = getExtension(url);

        if (ext == "png" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "bmp"){
            type ="image";
        }else if (ext == "swf"){
            type = "swf";
        }

        return type;

    }
    // this is the buggy code
    private function getExtension(str:String):String{
        return  str.split(".")[1];
    }
```

The bug is in the getExtension() function. I was expecting the dots only in the filename and the split returns two array elements and the 2nd element is the extension.

if you pass this variable

http://localhost/assets/images/Rendered/aksum_se.png

it returns png

http://19x.19x.24x.xxx/assets/images/Rendered/aksum_se.png

it returns 19x and thus its an unknown format. Well I fixed it.

Now I am little curious why my depth sorting is not working which is nto related to any image url but I think I will make it.